# react hook how to do type script multiple props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```js
export interface ProductsDatum {
    id: number
    sku: string
    name: string
    price: number
}

export interface Contacts {
    name: string
    phone: number
}

const Body = ({ products, contacts }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <span>hello</span>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Body
```

I want products prob to be of type `ProductsDatum`, and contacts prop to be of type `Contacts` How would you do it ?

Comment: not familiar with typescript, but by concept, you just need to annotate the prop to the interface(type) (`yourProp:yourType`) , so should be `interface ProductsDatum {...`  and annotate with `const Body = ({ products: ProductsDatum`, ...

Comment: no it doesn't work that way

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

Comment: not in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to define an interface for your component props which incorporates the other two types you're using and assigns them to the appropriate props.  You can then pass that interface as a generic to the `FunctionComponent` type for React functional components:

```
export interface ProductsDatum {
    id: number
    sku: string
    name: string
    price: number
}

export interface Contact {
    name: string
    phone: number
}

interface BodyProps {
    products: ProductsDatum[];
    contacts: Contact[];
}

const Body: FunctionComponent<BodyProps> = ({ products, contacts }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <span>hello</span>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I found [this article](https://fettblog.eu/typescript-react/components/) to be helpful for learning how to type React components properly.  Also it looks like `products` and/or `contacts` is meant to be an array, rather than a single object like you are defining in `ProductsDatum`/`Contacts`.  If that is indeed the case, you would need to define them either as `Array<ProductsDatum>` or `ProductsDatum[]` to avoid additional type errors.

Comment: Updated my answer to use the bracket form.  Also made ```Contact``` singular for semantics. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I usually use [Flow](https://flow.org/)

```
type Props = {
 id: number,
 sku: string,
 name: string,
 price: number
};


function Body(props: Props) {
  // code...
}
```